# assign a background color to a specific element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What can I do so that the small arrow in front of the text "ajout" also takes the background color. That is to say fill all the space of the text "ajout" with the color black. Here is my code.

this is a breadcrumb here is my code

```
 <div class="breadcrumb-container hidden-xs"  style="height: 30px;">
     <ol class="breadcrumb col-md-4" style="background-color: transparent !important;margin-top: -10px;">
         <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
         <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
         <li ><a style="background-color : #000000;color: #ffffff">Ajout</a></li>
     </ol>
 </div>
```

[image]

After @Aviboy 2006 code[image]

css

```
    .breadcrumb {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
      list-style: none;
      background-color: #eaecf4;
      border-radius: 0.35rem;
    }

    .breadcrumb-item + .breadcrumb-item {
      padding-left: 0.5rem;
    }

    .breadcrumb-item + .breadcrumb-item::before {
      display: inline-block;
      padding-right: 0.5rem;
      color: #858796;
      content: "/";
    }

    .breadcrumb-item + .breadcrumb-item:hover::before {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .breadcrumb-item + .breadcrumb-item:hover::before {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .breadcrumb-item.active {
  color: #858796;
}
```

Comment: Does "Ajout" mean "Add"?

Comment: @JakeParis I suppose your name doesn't mean you are from Paris. Ajout = add in French.

Comment: if possible add your css also. but if you apply background color to li.